# What are the ramifications of clearing Fort Independence?

Tags: xbox-360, fallout-3

I wound up visiting Fort Independence last night, and Protector Casdin took the Outcast Power Armor I was wearing, leaving me essentially naked. This couldn't stand, so ... I opened fire.

I lost a bit of karma for taking out him and Defender Morgan, and another tiny bit for opening up Fort Independence itself, but no karma losses inside for anything, including the wholesale slaughter of all the Brotherhood Outcasts.

What are the ramifications of this action? Will all Brotherhood Outcasts in the Wastes now be hostile? Will there be no more Brotherhood Outcasts? Are there no ramifications of any significance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Fallout 3 wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fort_Independence), it sounds like the only ramification is that all other Brotherhood Outcasts will become hostile (except those in Operation Anchorage), and you won't be able to do the repeating quest for them anymore (since the NPC you turn that quest in to is dead).

Comment: Luckily I already took care of Operation: Anchorage ...